# Display all Prime Factors from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, factors

The following program is written in python. Is there a more efficient way to write this program? Suggestions and criticism are welcome. You can also comment about my variable naming practices and code readability.

```
# int ----> list
# returns factor list of a num
def factor(num):
    factors = []
    for i in range(num):
        if not (i == 0 or i == 1):
            if num % i == 0:
                factors.append(i)
    return factors

# int ----> bool
# returns true if num is prime
def prime(num):
    for i in range(num):
        if not(i == 0 or i == 1):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
    return True

# main
# prints the factors of a number which are prime
def primeFactorization():
    num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
    factors = factor(num)
    prime_factors = []

    for item in factors:
        if prime(item):
            prime_factors.append(item)
    print(prime_factors)

primeFactorization()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both of your functions `prime` and `factor` you have something like:

```
for i in range(num):
    if not (i == 0 or i == 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
```

when you could shorten by using [`range(start,stop)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
for i in range(2,num):
    if num % i == 0:
        factors.append(i)
```